# how to reinitialize log4j2 configuration?

Tags: configuration, log4j2

After an initial configuration of log4j2 with:

```
Configurator.initialize(null, configLocation);
```

I would like to reinitialize it with a different URL

```
Configurator.initialize(null, configLocation2);
```

The problem is that the second call is ignored. I believe that once the LoggerContext is STARTED it will ignore reconfigurations.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a LoggerContext you can call

```
context.setConfigLocation(configLocation)
```

where configLocation is a URI.  That will force a reconfiguration.